# Delay on exit in SpringBoot console application

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, console-application

I created a simple test SpringBoot Console app with a spring-boot initializer.
Basic stuff was added: simple test entity, repository, and EclipseLink dependency. Postgresql DB is used as storage.

All things work as expected except one:
application wait 1 minute after completion of CommandLineRunner.

In the logs below
CommandLineRunner execution completed at 11:52:32,
then something was happening (according to logs in hikaripool),
finally application execution completed only at 11:53:31 (one minute after business logic completion)

```
2020-07-28 11:52:32.722 DEBUG 17072 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Closing JPA EntityManager [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl@5300cac] after transaction
2020-07-28 11:53:01.553 DEBUG 17072 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Before cleanup stats (total=5, active=0, idle=5, waiting=0)
2020-07-28 11:53:01.554 DEBUG 17072 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - After cleanup  stats (total=5, active=0, idle=5, waiting=0)
2020-07-28 11:53:01.555 DEBUG 17072 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Fill pool skipped, pool is at sufficient level.
2020-07-28 11:53:31.472 DEBUG 17072 --- [extShutdownHook] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@7905a0b8, started on Tue Jul 28 11:52:27 ALMT 2020
2020-07-28 11:53:31.480  INFO 17072 --- [extShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

Can anybody tell me please - what is the reason of delay before application completion?

Some additional info:
Described delay happens only on SpringBoot versions 2.3.X.
On SpringBoot 2.2.8 application works smoothly.